# Compiling a project based on OpenCV and ROS in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-construction, opencv, cmake

I am receiving an error when running CMake (actually rosmake) on my project. I have already installed OpenCV, but I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libCornerHelper.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_legacy
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stitching
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gpu
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_objdetect
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_calib3d
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_features2d
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_video
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ml
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_flann
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../lib/libCornerHelper.so] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't run `ldconfig` after you installed OpenCV. Or, the path where OpenCV is installed isn't in `ld.so.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, he could not find opencv to link against your project. Did you install it in somewhere else other than /usr or /usr/local?

If so, you need to add the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and so on.
What does your system say when you run this?

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

If you get something like this, then your system is ok.

```
-I/opt/opencv/include/opencv -I/opt/opencv/include  -L/opt/opencv/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

but if you don't, your system is not able to find it and cmake will not find it either:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'opencv' found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenCV in ROS, the appropriate link flags and paths should be picked up automatically if you have declared a dependency on opencv2 in your manifest.xml file.

If you are still having issues, I suggest you search [ROS Answers](http://answers.ros.org) and, if you don't find anything, ask your question there. That is the official ROS support forum and will likely get you a better answer to ROS specific problems than StackOverflow.